# Script goes ghost when dynamic content is loaded

Tags: jquery, scripting, load

After loading a PHP template (using jQuery's load function), this simple script won't make the DIV go away:

```
$("#trigger").click(function(event){
$("#removeThisDIV").hide();
```

The HTML bit:

```
<p id="trigger">X</p>
```

Tried to remove other DIVs, before the load -- it works just fine. After the load, the script went dead. Ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use event delegation with [`live`](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/live), as after you call `$.load` the newly injected elements will not have the click event handler bound to them:

```
$("#trigger").live("click",function(event){
    $("#removeThisDIV").hide();
});
```

Alternatively, use $.load's callback:

```
$('#blah').load('some.html', function() {
    $("#trigger").click(function() {
        $("#removeThisDIV").hide();
    });
});
```

For `live` to work, you will need to be using jQuery 1.3 or greater. Hope that helped.

Answer (score 1):

As karim79 mentions, the div you want to use as the trigger wasn't part of the DOM when you assigned the click function, so it doesn't have the needed functionality. Of course, you could simply place the js in the PHP template itself;

```
<p id="trigger" onclick="$('#removeThisDIV').hide();">X</p>
```

Make sure to include jquery above this element though, or it'll throw a "$ not recognised" error.

Comment: I'd rather handle these functions from the scripts file, but thanks for your effort and attention.